# City, State, Zip, Country list/script for sql server table

Tags: sql-server, geolocation

I have been searching around for the best source for City, State, Zip, Country to use in an application.  I have found the set at GeoNames.org and it seems very comprehensive.  However there is not a simple import into SQL Server.  I also believe the USPS has something similar.

Does anyone know a good reliable source that is easily imported into SQL Server for this information?  Or maybe even some better Googling terms?

Comment: I always use http://www.usps.com/ncsc/lookups/usps_abbreviations.html.  It probably won't help the original poster, but it might help someone else reading this.

Comment: By 'easily import' you mean you want their database in a sql server import friendly format?

Comment: I guess I'm mostly interested in finding an accurate robust list of cities, states, zip, countries. I can figure out the import. Just wanted to know what others were using for their "source" for their data.

Answer (score 1):

There is a script to load data from geonames in a blog I wrote a while ago.  Hopefully it helps.

[SQL Server Zipcode Latitude/Longitude proximity distance search](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/sql-server-zipcode-latitude-longitude-pr)

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just get the CSV files and bulk-load them into your data base.  How much simpler do you want?

Comment: Does the geonames offer a CSV?  I didn't see that format on their website.